# Correct me please . The code I wrote was in the notebook

Tags: python

```
class Student:
    workshop = 'python'
    def _init_(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def describe(self):
        print(self.name,"is",self.age,"years old and participating in",
              Student.workshop,"class")
        return

student1 = Student("Sridhar", 35 )
student1.name
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the errors you got

Comment: it's `__init__`, not `_init_`. I'm voting to close this because it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init` method expects two underscores `__`. Hence,

Change this:

```
def _init_(self, name, age):
```

to this:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
```

So:

```
class Student:
    workshop = 'python'
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def describe(self):
        print(self.name,"is",self.age,"years old and participating in",
              Student.workshop,"class")
        return

student1 = Student("Sridhar", 35)
print(student1.name)
student1.describe()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sridhar
Sridhar is 35 years old and participating in python class
```

Comment: srudent1.describe() to student1.describe()